# How to remove everything after specific character in csv

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd like to remove everything after `?` character in my csv.

Currently, it's like this: `abc?123`

I'd like to have it like this: `abc`

This is my code:

```
with open('Health.csv', 'r') as file, open('Health2.csv', 'w') as file2: 
    for line in file:
        line2 = line.rstrip('?')
        print(line2)
        file2.write(line2)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rstrip()` just removes that one character from the right-side, if present -- it will also remove multiple `?`s... e.g. if the string was `'abc???'` it will return  `'abc'`.

If `?` is not the final or rightmost character or characters, `rstrip()` is not going to do anything.

Instead do:

```
line2 = line.split('?')[0]
```

which splits on any `?`, and the `[0]` just takes the part before the first `?` if there are multiple. Example:

```
In [43]: 'a?b?c?'.split('?')[0]
Out[43]: 'a'
```

Comment: You could save all but the first split, you don't use them anyway: `line.split('?' ,1)[0] `.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('Health.csv', 'r') as file, open('Health2.csv', 'w') as file2: 
    for line in file:
        line2 = line.split('?')[0] 
        print(line2)
        file2.write(line2)
```

Comment: [This solution has already been posted along with an explanation](/a/70222958/4518341)

Comment: @wjandrea I did not see. I did not read. I browsed quickly. Excuse me

Comment: Sorry, I didn't find that particular question. Excuse me too :)